# Can't access functions made through prototype with WebdriverJS

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, prototype

So, I'm using selenium webdriver with javascript, the browser is firefox.
The `base_page` looks like this:

```
function Page() {

    this.driver = new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
      const driver = this.driver;

      this.visit = async(url) => {
        try {
          return await driver.get(url);
        } finally {
          console.log("visit: OK");
        }
      };

...
```

The `home_page` looks like this:

```
const Page = require('./base_page');
Page.prototype.requestBtn = async() => {


    try {
        await this.write('input', 'user@fakemail.com');
        return {
          opacity: await this.find('.btn-lg').getCssValue('opacity'),
          state: await this.find('.btn-lg').isEnabled()
        };
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }

};
...
```

In the `mocha.test.js` I import the `home_page`. I can use the functions created in `base_page`, but can't access functions in `home_page`.
For example, `page.visit()` and `page.quit()` are qorking, but `page.requestBtn()` not.

```
const assert = require('assert');
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const Page = require('../lib/home_page');
let page;


describe('Test', () => {
  beforeEach(async() => {
    page = new Page();
    await page.visit('https://library-app.firebaseapp.com');
  });


  afterEach(async() => {
    await page.quit();
  });


  it("Example", async() => {
    await page.requestBtn();
  });

...
```